# Why 360° is assigned to circle full turn ? Not any other number?

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Please look at this question

https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/9011243?noredirect=1

A user comment this so I thought of asking here

> You mean why did we decide on using 360 degrees? I don't know for sure, but question would probably belong on hsm.stackexchange.com. I assume the reason is because 360 is highly composite, which also explains why the clock has 12 hours. –
> Elliot G
> 1 hour ago

Another user comment it

> Babylonian scholars liked the number 360 because it has many divisors, and from there it became popular in antiquity (also because a few easily constructible angles have integer measure). An alternative system where the right angle is 100 degrees (the so-called centesimal degree) was proposed by revolutionary French academics, but it barely spread ouside of some surviving niche. In my opinion presenting degrees (sexagesimal or otherwise) as anything more than a celebrated relic which has many practical uses is a distortion of our current understanding of angles, which is radians. –
> Saucy O'Path

So basically that 1st user comment has stated my question " why we took a whole round or circle into 360 parts only naming each part angle as 1° not a circle with parts 540 , 260 etc etc.. only 360??

2nd user said it due to **Babylonian history**

Can you explain it history of dividing circle in 360° only??

Answer (score 1):

A full circle is assigned 360 degrees because the Babylonians and the Sumerians used the sexagesimal (base-60) system of counting. As discussed in an [article on Wonder Quest](http://web.archive.org/web/20130520192640/http://www.wonderquest.com/circle.htm), this, in turn, had come from their observation of the Sun completing a complete circle around the Earth in about 360 days:

> The Sumerians watched the Sun, Moon, and the five visible planets
> (Mercury, Venus, Mars, Jupiter, and Saturn), primarily for omens. They
> did not try to understand the motions physically. They did, however,
> notice the circular track of the Sun's annual path across the sky and
> knew that it took about 360 days to complete one year's circuit.
> Consequently, they divided the circular path into 360 degrees to track
> each day's passage of the Sun's whole journey. This probably happened
> about 2400 BC.